# CI/CD Multi-instance mobile app pipeline matrix in combination with variable groups

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, maui, cicd

I created a Multi-instance mobile app pipeline. It creates an apk and an aab per tenant (client). To do so I make use of a pipeline parameter where I can set multiple tenants at a time:

```
- name: Tenants
  displayName: "Select Tenants to build for"
  type: object
  default:
  - ExampleClient
  - ExampleClient2
```

Now in the BuildAndroid stage I want to build an .apk and .aab per tenant which I use a matrix for and a compile time for loop:

```
- stage: BuildAndroid
  variables:
  - group: ${{ TenantName }}
  jobs:
  - job: 'BuildAndroid'
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ${{ each tenant in parameters.Tenants }}:
          ${{ format('{0}_APK', tenant) }}:
            TenantName: ${{ tenant }}
            BuildFormat: 'apk'
            SignAndroid: $(SignAndroidApk)
            BuildApp: $(PackageAndroidApk)
          ${{ format('{0}_AAB', tenant) }}:
            TenantName: ${{ tenant }}
            BuildFormat: 'aab'
            SignAndroid: $(SignAndroidAab)
            BuildApp: $(PackageAndroidAab)
    displayName: 'Build Android'
```

*"- group: ${{ TenantName }}"* is responsible for setting the tenant-specific variables and secrets but TenantName is not available because it's part of the matrix for loop. Variable groups can't be set dynamically at runtime using $() syntax. So how can I go about this?

```
  (Line: 53, Col: 12): Unrecognized value: 'TenantName'. Located at position 1 within 
  expression: TenantName.
```

**What I expect:**
I can select multiple tenants before the pipeline runs and it builds the apk and aab for all selected tenants based on tenant specific variables and secrets.

How can I change my approach to make this work?

Comment: You have mentioned "`- group: ${{ TenantName }}` is responsible for setting the tenant-specific variables and secrets but `TenantName` is not available because it's **part of the matrix for loop**". So assuming the variable groups are named with `each` value in `parameters.Tenants`, you can try the sample in the answer below. Otherwise, please specify based on which value you would expect to dynamically use a variable group. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you would expect to reference variable groups dynamically with the group names of `${{ TenantName }}`, whose names are the same values as those defined in `parameters.Tenants`, the sample below works. As required, you can also define multiple tenants for `parameters.Tenants` at queue time and pipeline jobs will be expanded for `each` value in `parameters.Tenants` and matrix with values retrieved from respective variable group.

```
parameters:
- name: Tenants
  displayName: "Select Tenants to build for"
  type: object
  default:
  - ExampleClient1
  - ExampleClient2
stages:
- stage: BuildAndroid
  jobs:
  - ${{ each tenant in parameters.Tenants }}:
    - job: 'BuildAndroid_${{ tenant }}'
      dependsOn: []
      displayName: 'Build Android for ${{ tenant }}'
      variables:
      - group: ${{ tenant }}
      strategy:
        matrix:
          ${{ format('{0}_APK', tenant) }}:
            TenantName: ${{ tenant }}
            BuildFormat: 'apk'
            SignAndroid: $(SignAndroidApk)
            BuildApp: $(PackageAndroidApk)
          ${{ format('{0}_AAB', tenant) }}:
            TenantName: ${{ tenant }}
            BuildFormat: 'aab'
            SignAndroid: $(SignAndroidAab)
            BuildApp: $(PackageAndroidAab)
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo "TenantName: $(TenantName)"
          echo "BuildFormat: $(BuildFormat)"
          echo "SignAndroid: $(SignAndroid)"
          echo "BuildApp: $(BuildApp)"
```

[image]